# How to implement wheel widget like in iPhone?

Tags: android, android-widget

I would like to implement a time settings wheel widget like the one iPhone has (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/art/ui_datetimepicker.jpg).

1. Should I use GlSurfaceView or just extend View?
2. Should I make it as a compound View (it would consist of several Views) or draw everything on the Canvas in onDraw?
3. In case I won't extend GlSurfaceView, how to do (smooth) animations? Start a Thread and call postInvalidate()?

Answer (score 6):

http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

Comment: I know about this, but it doesn't have animations and when I move the wheel with my finger it doesn't move smoothly but "jumps".

Comment: Ah good to know, I was looking at using this for a project but hadn't tested it out yet.  I'll keep looking and post here if I find anything better.

Answer (score 3):

I've put my code for an animated wheel widget here:

http://code.google.com/p/smooth-wheel/

Comment: your code ie well,but  in your main.xml,you should use com.sinkpoint.smoothwheel.WheelView,if it have mistake.

Comment: you are right, did catch that with the last refactor. Code is updated.

Answer (score 0):

the answer @mbaird gave seems to support animations afaik in 2.0 via their slot machine demo. is this the kind of animation you are looking for?